# take values once in SQl

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my SQl:

```
$branches = DB::select('select distinct programs.id as program_id,programs.program_name as program_name,branches.id as branch_id,branches.branch_name as branch_name from programs,branches where programs.company_id=? and branches.company_id=?' ,[$company_id,$company_id]);
```

bu when I call branch_id/program_id for a specific "company_id" it repeats same id multiple times. but I want to show the values just once. what can I do for this?

Comment: Based on your comment below about wanting to just get the values from the two tables separately, is there a reason you don't just run two separate selects? e.g. `$branches = DB::select...` and `$programs = DB::select...`

Comment: I have tried this,It works also, but problem is can u tell me how can I pass two variable here   `return Response::json($branches);`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

```
select distinct programs.id as program_id,programs.program_name as program_name,branches.id as branch_id,branches.branch_name as branch_name from programs,branches where programs.company_id=? and branches.company_id=programs.company_id
```

Look up internet how SQL joins work

Comment: I don't want to join that two tables, just want to get the values differently from that two tables.